# Noblex 150/U. early model serial # 002 816 filters, lens shift

Tags: filters, noblex

I am starting to use the Noblex 150/U I purchased a few years ago.  Learning slowly all of the intricacies not explained in the manual. I have the original printed manual for the model.

1. Seems fairly obvious, but to make sure, the filter rectangle is positioned vertically?
2. Does the 150 have the same lost frame, slot closure as that explained in the following question: [Is it possible to install a filter (or remove one) in a Noblex camera without wasting/exposing film?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/128403)
3. The manual for the U model talks about (again an early model 150/U), lens shift being accomplished by moving forks that "surround" the lens from the left side.  I've applied some pressure, but am not that interested in the shift feature unless I'm sure that the camera has the feature, is the place to apply the pressure or it's just locked up from age.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have a 135 model, and have never used a medium format model, but there's obviously a level of overlap in the design of how all Noblex cameras operate.

First question is an interesting one – I never gave it any thought. I think the filters are only rectangular just to make space for an area to grip the filter. I don't believe it actually makes any difference in which orientation the filter is applied to the lens – in all cases, light goes through the filter glass to the lens, and in my experience, no vignetting or anything like that occurs.

Second question... I've checked both the English-language manual and German-language manual for the medium format models, and there's no mention of tilting the camera forward, as the 135 manual instructs. So, that leads me to believe that either the slit cover isn't there on the medium format models, or else it functions in a different way. You could do some trial-and-error – with the camera back open, and no film loaded – to see if you can replicate the behaviour of the 135 models.

Third question... On [camera-wiki.org](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Noblex), the 6/150U model is indeed listed as having 5mm of lens shift available.

Comment: Those are great answers. Thanks.  For future folks that may find this on a web search, like me... I tried moving the "forks" and they indeed moved up and down with ease.  A bit of a catch at the top position to keep it in place.  I'll post about exposing the film when I get some back.  However.  I'm just remembering the instructions say very clearly that the drum must be turned counter clockwise, if clockwise the film will be exposed.  That probably is the answer but will know soon.  Thanks again